# In single slit diffraction what happens to the straight wavefronts which are stopped by the barrier?

Tags: waves, diffraction

[image]

I cannot understand what happens to the waves hitting the barrier ...does it get absorbed by barrier? or does it reflect back ?

Comment: Any particular reason you're asking? If you're just concerned about the diffraction pattern beyond the barrier, I don't think that it matters whether the barrier absorbs or reflects the light on it.

Comment: actually if it reflected back? would'nt the reflected wave cancel out(if it reflects all) or reduce the amplitude of (if some gets absorbed)  the incoming wave?

Comment: can you please tell me ... where is my misconception?

Comment: No, the reflected wave and the incident wave won't just cancel each other out as they're passing through the air. They will go right through each other.

Answer (score 0):

> actually if it reflected back? would'nt the reflected wave cancel
>   out(if it reflects all) or reduce the amplitude of (if some gets
>   absorbed) the incoming wave?

The light absorbed or reflected by the barrier should not have any effect on the light passing through the slot.

If the light is reflected, it will interfere with the incoming light, but that interference will affect the incoming light only where the interference will take place, i.e., before the barrier, and won't have any effect on the incoming light after the barrier, where it actually matters. You can check out [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/413771/direction-of-wave-propagation-unchanged-after-superposition/413789#413789) for details.

If the light is absorbed by the barrier, it would have no effect on the incoming light passing through the slot, before or after the barrier. So, this case seems to be more obvious.

Comment: @RixVii Glad to help.